# OnPaint override is never called

Tags: c#, winforms

I have been at this for a few days and it is driving me mad. I have a control that inherits from System.Windows.Forms.Panel and I'm trying to override OnPaint. It just plain, outright IGNORES it.

```
public class CollapsiblePanel : System.Windows.Forms.Panel
{
  public CollapsiblePanel()
  {
   //
   // Required for the Windows Form Designer
   //
   InitializeComponent();

   //
   // TODO: Add any constructor code after InitializeComponent call
   //
   SetStyle
    (
     ControlStyles.AllPaintingInWmPaint | 
     ControlStyles.UserPaint      | ControlStyles.DoubleBuffer   |
     ControlStyles.ResizeRedraw     | ControlStyles.Selectable ,
     true
    );
        }

  protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
  {
            // This never runs no matter what I try!
            base.OnPaint(e);
        }
}
```

Comment: Works on my machine... can you post an example of how you're using this control?

Comment: FlowLayoutPanel.Controls.Add(new CollapsiblePanel());

Comment: @Stacey, I'm afraid you're going to have to be more specific.  I can drop your `CollapsiblePanel` onto a `FlowLayoutPanel` on a `Form` and it executes that method just fine.  Either you've modified the designer-generated `InitializeComponent`, or some control in your hierarchy is blocking WM_PAINT messages.

Comment: How do you know it never runs?

Comment: Because I insert a dubugging marker there, and it never picks it up, but the control continues to operate just fine aside from what ever is put in the OnPaint override. I can't be any more specific, this is literally 100% of the information I have.

Comment: I can't think of anything I'm missing, but I'll try. I'll create a FlowLayoutPanel on a Form, and call the Add method in a Timer Tick Event to it's Controls property. I'll add a new CollapsiblePanel (Not yet anything but the skeleton panel you see above) - and put some kind of code in the OnPaint method. It just adds the panel to the flowlayout and never runs the Onpaint method.

Comment: Still works on my machine... you should put this code into a new Winforms project and gradually build it out until you're able to reproduce the issue.  There's definitely something external that's affecting you.

Comment: No repro.  It doesn't have to run when you put it into a FLP, OnPaint only runs when the control is actually in view.  Eliminate that first.

Comment: I'm agreeing with everyone else. My CollapliblePanel class looks identical to the one above, except I've got a simple Graphics line draw in the OnPaint method. Other than that, I followed everything said so far: I've got a FLP and a Timer. On Timer.Tick, I add a new CollapsiblePanel to the FLP. As soon as the tick occurs, I see the panel with the line drawn. There's got to be more going on here...

Comment: Still no idea. I'm going to have to chock this one up to some kind of strange bug, I'll try on a new install.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

I have the same problem just with a ProgressBar, when i try to override the OnPaint.. It's never called.

---

I found the solution here: http://web.archive.org/web/20140214234801/http://osix.net/modules/article/?id=826

You must create a constructor and enable user-painting like this:

```
SetStyle(ControlStyles.AllPaintingInWmPaint | ControlStyles.UserPaint | ControlStyles.OptimizedDoubleBuffer | ControlStyles.ResizeRedraw, true);
```

Default values, probably vary depending on framework version and OS.

Comment: this worked, but for a different reason!! Apparently, the ORDER in which they go in actually matters (this doesn't make any sense - aren't enums just bit codes? ) - changing the order solved the problem for me.

Comment: @Stacey: Yes, enums ARE bit flags, and order of the enums when logically OR-ing them is NOT important. `SetStyle` method gets the same combination of flags regardless of the order in which you specify them.

Answer (score 3):

Call `this.Invalidate()` when you want to call `OnPaint`