# Create custom ComboBox with rounded corners in Windows Forms

Tags: c#, winforms, combobox, onpaint

I want to create a custom combo-box with rounded corners and gradient color. I have implemented the same feature in `Button` by overriding the `OnPaint` method. But it is not working for `ComboBox`. Any help will be appreciated.

The code I am using for overriding `OnPaint` is given below:

```
protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs paintEvent)
{
     Graphics graphics = paintEvent.Graphics;

     SolidBrush backgroundBrush = new SolidBrush(this.BackColor);
     graphics.FillRectangle(backgroundBrush, ClientRectangle);

     graphics.SmoothingMode = SmoothingMode.AntiAlias;

     Rectangle rectangle = new Rectangle(ClientRectangle.X, ClientRectangle.Y, ClientRectangle.Width - 1, ClientRectangle.Height - 1);
     GraphicsPath graphicsPath = RoundedRectangle(rectangle, cornerRadius, 0);
     Brush brush = new LinearGradientBrush(rectangle, gradientTop, gradientBottom, LinearGradientMode.Horizontal);
     graphics.FillPath(brush, graphicsPath);

     rectangle = new Rectangle(ClientRectangle.X, ClientRectangle.Y, ClientRectangle.Width - 1, ClientRectangle.Height - 100);
     graphicsPath = RoundedRectangle(rectangle, cornerRadius, 2);
     brush = new LinearGradientBrush(rectangle, gradientTop, gradientBottom, LinearGradientMode.Horizontal);
     graphics.FillPath(brush, graphicsPath);
}

private GraphicsPath RoundedRectangle(Rectangle rectangle, int cornerRadius, int margin)
{
    GraphicsPath roundedRectangle = new GraphicsPath();
    roundedRectangle.AddArc(rectangle.X + margin, rectangle.Y + margin, cornerRadius * 2, cornerRadius * 2, 180, 90);
    roundedRectangle.AddArc(rectangle.X + rectangle.Width - margin - cornerRadius * 2, rectangle.Y + margin, cornerRadius * 2, cornerRadius * 2, 270, 90);
    roundedRectangle.AddArc(rectangle.X + rectangle.Width - margin - cornerRadius * 2, rectangle.Y + rectangle.Height - margin - cornerRadius * 2, cornerRadius * 2, cornerRadius * 2, 0, 90);
    roundedRectangle.AddArc(rectangle.X + margin, rectangle.Y + rectangle.Height - margin - cornerRadius * 2, cornerRadius * 2, cornerRadius * 2, 90, 90);
    roundedRectangle.CloseFigure();
    return roundedRectangle;
}
```

Comment: _"But it is not working for Combobox."_ Please be more specific. *How* is it not working?

Comment: Please provide the full code. "RoundedRectangle" method is not declared as also some parameters.

Comment: @stakx I wanted to create a custom control. I have overridden the OnPaint() event of Button. It worked perfectly. I have used the same code to customize the Combobox. But for combobox, it seems like the overriding is not happening. I am not sure whether the way I am customizing the Combobox is right since I am new to WinForms.

Comment: May be this will help [Textbox with rounded corners](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/17453/Textbox-with-rounded-corners)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I was able to find a solution to this problem. Actually, the problem was that OnPaint event was not getting called for Combobox. So I had to do the following changes.

```
public CustomComboBox()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    SetStyle(ControlStyles.UserPaint, true);
}
```

I had to call SetStyle() method inside the constructor so that OnPaint() event will get called.

I found this post as helful : [OnPaint override is never called](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2215393/onpaint-override-is-never-called)

The same solution can be used for Custom TextBoxes.

Comment: Any chance you could provide a full sample of this? I've added the functions and the line to my project and I can't get it to work.  It'd be really helpful to see a working example of this.