# Why is my overridden OnPaint method not invoked?

Tags: c#, winforms, drawing, onpaint

I have created custom picture buttons and now need to do some additional drawing in the main Form (that is using these buttons), so I overrode its `OnPaint` method.

For some reason it is never called and I do not know why.

```
public partial class Form1: Form
{   
 protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnPaint(e);
    }
}
```

Comment: might be helpful http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2215393/onpaint-override-is-never-called

Comment: Thanks, yet my problem occurs in the main Form, not inherited controls. Tried the solution, does not work.

Comment: We need more information. Are you inheriting from `Form` like: `public class MainForm : Form`?

Comment: Sorry - no, this is plain Form1 : Form. I added panel to which I am adding programatically picture buttons. These buttons have OnPaint overridden as well and for them it works fine.

Answer (score 3):

I found out what was the problem - there was a GroupPanel with docking set to Fill in the Main form.