# OnPaint override is never called in some controls

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2022

The topic [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2215393/onpaint-override-is-never-called) is old but I have the same problem, OnPaint works for Button but not for DataTimePicker, TextBox or ProgressBar

When I set a breakpoint on the OnPaint event it doesn't trigger it at all

I read this text [Link](https://web.archive.org/web/20140214234801/http://osix.net/modules/article/?id=826) and followed the instructions but to no avail

```
Public Class Form2
    
        Private Sub Form2_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    
            Me.SetStyle(ControlStyles.AllPaintingInWmPaint, True)
            Me.SetStyle(ControlStyles.UserPaint, True)
            Me.SetStyle(ControlStyles.OptimizedDoubleBuffer, True)
            Me.SetStyle(ControlStyles.ResizeRedraw, True)
    
            Dim customComboBox1 As New CustomComboBox()
            customComboBox1.Location = New Point(50, 50)
    
            Me.Controls.Add(customComboBox1)
    
            customComboBox1.Invalidate()
    
        End Sub
    
    End Class

    Imports System.Windows.Forms
    
    Public Class CustomComboBox
        Inherits ComboBox
    
        Protected Overrides Sub OnPaint(e As PaintEventArgs)
            MyBase.OnPaint(e)
            Dim rectanglePen As New Pen(Color.Black, 2)
            e.Graphics.DrawRectangle(rectanglePen, New Rectangle(0, 0, Width - 1, Height - 1))
            rectanglePen.Dispose()
        End Sub
    
    End Class
```

Answer (score 2):

You have called `SetStyle` for the `Form` but you must call it for the `CustomComboBox`. You can do so in the constructor (`Sub New`).

```vb
Public Class CustomComboBox
    Inherits ComboBox

    Public Sub New()
        Me.SetStyle(ControlStyles.AllPaintingInWmPaint, True)
        Me.SetStyle(ControlStyles.UserPaint, True)
        Me.SetStyle(ControlStyles.OptimizedDoubleBuffer, True)
        Me.SetStyle(ControlStyles.ResizeRedraw, True)
    End Sub

    Protected Overrides Sub OnPaint(e As PaintEventArgs)
        MyBase.OnPaint(e)
        Dim rectanglePen As New Pen(Color.Black, 2)
        e.Graphics.DrawRectangle(rectanglePen, New Rectangle(0, 0, Width - 1, Height - 1))
        rectanglePen.Dispose()
    End Sub

End Class
```

This will also suppress drawing the the drop-down's down-arrow button. But you can draw your own like this (just add it to `OnPaint`):

```vb
e.Graphics.DrawLine(Pens.LightGray, Width - 18, 2, Width - 18, Height - 4)
e.Graphics.DrawString("V", Font, Brushes.Black, New PointF(Width - 16, 5))
```

---

You can also dispose the pen with a [Using Statement](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/statements/using-statement)

```vb
Protected Overrides Sub OnPaint(e As PaintEventArgs)
    MyBase.OnPaint(e)
    Using rectanglePen As New Pen(Color.Black, 2)
        e.Graphics.DrawRectangle(rectanglePen, New Rectangle(0, 0, Width - 1, Height - 1))
        e.Graphics.DrawLine(Pens.LightGray, Width - 18, 2, Width - 18, Height - 4)
        e.Graphics.DrawString("V", Font, Brushes.Black, New PointF(Width - 16, 5))
    End Using
End Sub
```

The pen will automatically be disposed at the end of the Using statement. Even if an unhandled exception should occur or if you exit the code block with e.g. a Return statement.

Comment: Thank you, logically, I mis understood the logic and thought that style rules were defined at the form level. Please, just one more question, is there a way to call the system rectangle and resize handle when the user clicks on the control, or do I have to draw it all?

Comment: In the forms designer the resize handle will be displayed automatically. At runtime it is never drawn. If you want to allow the user to resize at runtime you must draw and implement the logic yourself. But it is often easier to use, e.g., a `SplitContainer` together with appropriate `Anchor` or `Dock` settings for the combo box.

Comment: It is necessary to move the control on the form or change its size in runtime, I want to imitate the work of ToolBox, dragging the controls to the form and then managing the size or other attributes. I have successfully created everything but I have a problem with TextBox, ComboBox, ProgressBar or DataPicker controls, with them the square I draw does not appear, while with Button, CheckBox ... everything works fine. Thanks, I will definitely try to understand now that I have more answers.

Comment: WPF has a so called Adorner Layer which allows you place things above the form and all its controls. This does not exist in Winforms at runtime. But you may be able to place a transparent form above the real form to imitate such a thing. See also [Winforms: How to get Mouse Events for Transparent Control on a Transparent Form](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32389571/880990).

Comment: I would like to share my code but I am not allowed. I had to solve the resize control without the handles (the handles are not visible, but it is possible to resize). If I ever get unblocked, I'll be happy to share the code with you.

Comment: The problem is that you cannot draw outside of the bounds of the control. Therefore the handles will be at least partially hidden. This is why I am suggesting drawing on a transparent window floating above the real form.

Comment: I understand, but I managed to create handles for all other controls (Grid, GroupBox, Label, CheckBox) ... those controls have handles and for them resize works perfectly, even diagonally. What is the difference in the controls that some can and some can't I don't understand that?